# Why ipython says terminal unavailbles?

Tags: jupyter

I have installed anaconda. I added the anaconda path to my system variables but each time I fire up ipython notebook or jupyter notebook, it says terminals unavailable.

Has something gone wrong with my installation? I am someone out of academia and I am hoping for the kind help of a pro. Thank you,

Comment: the question is not very clear. So you go to the terminal, type 'jupyter notebook', browser opens up, and when you click on 'New', you don't see Python 3 under Notebooks? is this the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

Would you by any chance be under windows ?

If so you are out of luck, the ability to have an in-browser terminal is not available on windows for the moment. There is no active plan of making this work on windows either, unless someone with the technical knowledge  and a windows machine, improve the [underlying package](http://terminado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks yes I am on windows